# Scrapy getting values from other links

Tags: python, scrapy

```
def parse(self, response):
    list = {
        "name": response.css("#title::text").extract_first(),
        "images": []
    }

    for image in response.css("#images_link a::attr(href)").extract():
        list["images"].append(yield scrapy.Request(url=image, callback=self.parse_image))
        
    yield list
    
def parse_image(self, response):
    return [response.css("img::attr(alt)").extract(), response.css("img::attr(src)").extract()]
```

i wanna to scrap a page and also scrape some of its children links and append them to the main object of `list` but it returns many many objects back instead of one

how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you rename "list" to something else.

Request doesn't work like that, you'll need to pass the item ("dict1" in the example).

Here's an example (since you didn't provide the website's url I couldn't check it, but I hope you get the point):

```py
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "exampleSpider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        dict1 = {
            "name": response.css("#title::text").get(),
            "images": []
        }

        images_urls = response.css("#images_link a::attr(href)").getall()

        if images_urls:
            scrapy.Request(url=images_urls[0],
                           callback=self.parse_image,
                           cb_kwargs={'dict1': dict1, 'images_urls': images_urls[1:]})

    def parse_image(self, response, dict1, images_urls):
        if images_urls:
            dict1['images'].append([response.css("img::attr(alt)").getall(), response.css("img::attr(src)").getall()])
            scrapy.Request(url=images_urls[0],
                           callback=self.parse_image,
                           cb_kwargs={'dict1': dict1, 'images_urls': images_urls[1:]})
        else:
            yield dict1
```

Read these:
[request objects](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects),
[passing additional data to callback functions](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions)

Comment: so only way is to loop the request over its self with the new dict of data after removing the part we parsred?

Comment: It's not the only way but I find it convenient.

Comment: what is other ways i wanna learn all of them thank you

Comment: You can for example create a `counter` and check if it's bigger than the length of `images_urls`, if it is then yield the item, if not then recursively yield a scrapy request and pass the item and the urls list.